# insert optiont tag extract

Tags: php, html

hi everyone im a beginner in php and  i set des code but i have three proble 
the first problem after pressing the input button the information is not stored in db 
and second i have problem with space in line 12 and 15 
3 when i cancel the space i get this problem

> Undefined index: Service in C:\wamp64\www\call-me\insert.php on line 10
>   extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp64\www\call-me\insert.php on line 11
>
> Undefined variable: Femmedeménage in C:\wamp64\www\call-me\insert.php on line 12

```
    <?php
require("conn.php");

$Nom=$_POST['Nom'];
$Prenom=$_POST['Prenom'];
$Cin =$_POST['Cin'];
$Adress=$_POST['Adress'];
$Tell=$_POST['Tell'];
$Gsm=$_POST['Gsm'];
$Service= $_POST['Service'];
extract ($Service);
echo $Femmedeménage ;
echo $nounou;
echo $sécurité;
echo $assistancelesgensâgées;
echo $jardinage;
echo $gardinage;
echo $cuisinière;
echo $autres;
$Description=$_POST['Description'];
$query="INSERT INTO client VALUE('$Nom','$Prenom','$Cin','$Adress','Tell','Gsm','Service','Description')";
$result= @mysqli_query($query);
$lastItemID = @mysqli_insert_id();
if($result)
{
echo" il clineti e stato inserito con il numero :
ID: ".$lastItemID;

}

else{echo"error";}

?>





<html>
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystylefor.css">
</head>

<center>



<h2>Gestion de client</h2>
<body><form action="insert.php" method="POST">

<table>
<tr>
<td>Nom:</td><td><input type="text" name="Nom" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Prenom:</td><td><input type="text" name="Prenom"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cin / Passport :</td><td><input type="text" name="Cin"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Adress:</td><td><input type="text" name="Adress"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tell:</td><td><input type="text" name="Tell"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gsm:</td><td><input type="text" name="Gsm"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service:</td><td><select name="Service" form="Service">
   <option value=" "> Choise votre service </option>
  <option value="Femme de ménage ">Femme de ménage </option>
  <option value="nounou">nounou</option>
  <option value="sécurité">sécurité</option>
  <option value="assistance les gens âgées">assistance les gens âgées</option>
  <option value="jardinage">jardinage</option>
  <option value="gardinage">gardinage</option>
  <option value="cuisinière">cuisinière</option>
  <option value="autres">autres</option>
</select>
</tr>
<td>Description:</td><td><textarea name="Description"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</div>



<td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Ajouter" ></td>
</table>


</body></form></center></html>
```

Comment: Var_dump($_POST) and post it in your question. It seems it's empty

Comment: Hi Amin, I'm guessing that French, not English, is your primary language (which is fine). But you'd get better responses if you used punctuation and capitalisation in your question. Also, format your errors as code, so that others can read them more easily.

Comment: hi sonia hamilton my primary language is italian and this my first time in stackoverflow and i asking sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

I think you are completely Novice and i know in starting days of programming how it's feel when we are not clear about error but today is your lucky day i have a day off from office. So let get start with your full description answer here .

1. first of all do php and html or any other programming with plain English. Please do not mix the word or latter from your native language so set you computer or keyboards language plain english or usa or uk English.
2. Always do coding with proper indenting and spacing so that code is readable.
3. In **HTML Part** you are using the dropdown menu called `Service` in the second option value you are using `Femme de ménage` this word please do not use the space in `value` attributes replace your spaces with `_` underscore .
4. In **Php code** you are getting the error of `Undefined index:` with lots of variable name it is coming because you are using those variable even before they exists in your script. everything related to those variable in the php script comes into the action when you submit the button and **One more** problem is the you haven't checked for the `submit` button is pressed or not and it's having a value set or not.
5. So for this you have to check for the condition `if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) || $_POST['submit'] =='submit' )` and place rest of the inside the `condition block`.

> Undefined index: Service in C:\wamp64\www\call-me\insert.php on line 10 extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp64\www\call-me\insert.php on line 11

6. you are getting the above error because the `extract` function takes the argument as array and by you html code you are just getting only one value so it's not the array. Second Read the manual of [extract function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Third if you want to set the array value and want to get multiple value for
the `Service` select dropdown then you have to make the following changes in the code

`<select name="Service[]" multiple>`

and then you will be able to use `extract` function with it's proper meaning.

7. And i have changed the condition part of `if($result)` in my opinion `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if($rowcount ==1)` this will be good but have a try on both of them .

**AND BELOW IS THE UPDATED CODE HAVE A TRY**

```
<html>
    <head>

     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystylefor.css">
      </head>

     <center>



     <h2>Gestion de client</h2>
      <body>

        <form action="" method="POST">

           <table>
          <tr><td>Nom:</td>             <td><input type="text" name="Nom" > 
             </td></tr>
           <tr><td>Prenom:</td>         <td><input type="text" name="Prenom"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cin / Passport :</td> <td><input type="text" name="Cin"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Adress:</td>          <td><input type="text" name="Adress"></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Tell:</td>             <td><input type="text" name="Tell"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Gsm:</td>             <td><input type="text" name="Gsm"></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Service:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="Service[]" multiple>
      <option value=" "> Choise votre service </option>
      <option value="Femme_de_ménage ">Femme de ménage </option>
      <option value="nounou">nounou</option>
      <option value="sécurité">sécurité</option>
      <option value="assistance les gens âgées">assistance les gens âgées</option>
      <option value="jardinage">jardinage</option>
      <option value="gardinage">gardinage</option>
      <option value="cuisinière">cuisinière</option>
      <option value="autres">autres</option>
    </select>
</tr>
<tr><td>Description:</td><td><textarea name="Description"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>Submit</td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
  </form>


       </div>

       <?php
                 //require("conn.php");

                echo '<pre>';
                   print_r($_POST);
                  echo '</pre>';

      if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) || $_POST['submit'] =='submit' ){
        $Nom = $_POST['Nom'];
        $Prenom=$_POST['Prenom'];
        $Cin =$_POST['Cin'];
        $Adress=$_POST['Adress'];
        $Tell=$_POST['Tell'];
          $Gsm=$_POST['Gsm'];
          $Service=   $_POST['Service']  ;
          //extract ($Service);
        $Description=$_POST['Description'];

         /*
          echo $Femmedeménage ;
          echo $nounou;
          echo $sécurité;
          echo $assistancelesgensâgées;
          echo $jardinage;
          echo $gardinage;
          echo $cuisinière;
          echo $autres;
          */


          $query="INSERT INTO client VALUE('$Nom','$Prenom','$Cin','$Adress','$Tell','$Gsm','$Service','$Description'          )";

          $result= @mysqli_query($query);
          $lastItemID = @mysqli_insert_id();
          if($result)
          /*
          $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);   
          if($rowcount ==1)
              */
          {
            echo" il clineti e stato inserito con il numero :
            ID: ".$lastItemID;

          }else
          {
            echo "ERROR:: ". mysqli_error($your_db_connection_link);
          }
      } 
      ?>
```

if anything goes wrong kindly let me know .
I forget to mention that use your own database connection setting as you are using. 
THANKS

Comment: Thanks @amin-amin I don't know sharing fb account id here is good idea . kindly come to [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171938). Thumbs Up :)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you try a insert a record when open page.
Put your logic (php code) for insert in to a **if** condition, eg:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
.....
$query
....
}
```